# for loop inside phpmailer message?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have a table displayed with checkboxes against each row, a user can select multiple check boxes then click submit, this will then send an email using phpmailer.
I want the users selected items to be included in the body of the email. I know the below is wrong but could someone show me how to do this please ?

This is what I have so far ... it does send an email , but only the first selection in the array is in the body.

```
$select = $_POST['select'];
if(empty($select)) 
{
 echo("You didn't make any selections.");
} 
else
{
$count = count($select);
 for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
{

$to = "test@test.com";
$subject = "Booking Reguest";
$message = '    
<html>
<head>
<title>Booking Request</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please create bookings for the following ...</p>
<p>'. $select[$i] .',</p>
<p>Kind regards</p>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</body>
</html>';
$headers = 'From: noreply@test.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
    }
```

Appreciate the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looping the whole mail instead of the select only?

Please provide us your HTML code but, if I've understood the problem, this will fix it:

```
$select = $_POST['select'];
if(empty($select)) 
{
 echo("You didn't make any selections.");
} 
else
{
$count = count($select);

$to = "test@test.com";
$subject = "Booking Reguest";
$message = '    
<html>
<head>
<title>Booking Request</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Please create bookings for the following ...</p>
<p>';
 for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
if ($i == (count($select)-1)) {
$message .= $select[$i];
}
else {
$message .= $select[$i] .", ";
}
};
$message .= '</p>
<p>Kind regards</p>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</body>
</html>';
$headers = 'From: noreply@test.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
```

In this way it will put the checkbox elements with a comma between them ignoring the last comma.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Also, you're missing some `<br />` tags after each `<p>`, aren't you? In this way you will receive the e-mail with inline text!